# Jquery post to mvc 4 controller not passing data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to pass data from JQuery to an MVC 4 controller.  The controller gets invoked, but no data is passed.  In the past I always just used form serialization, but that's not appropriate here.

My Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Write(VideoSessionEnvelope envelope)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        envelope = Log.Write(envelope);
    }
    var result = Json(envelope);
    return result;
}
```

We use an envelope class as a container for all view models

```
public class VideoSessionEnvelope : BaseEnvelope
{
    public VideoSessionEnvelope()
    {
        SessionStart = new VideoSessionStartViewModel();
    }
    public Guid? LogEntryID { get; set; }
    public VideoSessionStartViewModel SessionStart { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The view model

```
public class VideoSessionStartViewModel: IViewModel
{
    public string SessionId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

And finally the javascript

```
var Logging = Logging || {};
Logging.VideoSession = function () {
    var Start = function (sessionId, userId, message) {
    var envelope = {
            SessionStart: {
                "SessionId": sessionId,
                "UserId": userId,
                "Message": message
            }
        }
        var data = JSON.stringify(envelope);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Logging/Write",
            data: data,
            datatype: "application/json",
            success: function (result) {
                return result;
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                return error;
            }
        });
    };

    return {
        Start: Start
    };
}();
```

According to Firebug the data is passed as

```
JSON
SessionStart  Object { SessionId="sessionIdVal", UserId=123, Message="messageValue"}
Message      "messageValue"
SessionId    "sessionIdVal"
UserId       123
```

The controller gets called, but the properties in the view model are always null.  I've tried several variations on the theme, nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your data in a literal with the name as envelope so it will be picked up by the Model Binder:

```
data: { envelope: data },
```

**UPDATE**

Remove the call to `JSON.stringify()`, it is not strictly necessary to serialize the object literal.

Comment: That was one of the options I tried, along with var envelope = { envelope: { SessionStart: { ...

Comment: @AllenJergensen How about removing the `JSON.stringify()` call and just passing the data as is.  I don't think it is necessary to serialize it.

Comment: Thanks asymptoticFault - the issue was the stringify (with a minor tweak)
...            

    var envelope = {
            'SessionStart.SessionId': sessionId,
            'SessionStart.UserId': userId,
            'SessionStart.Message': message
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Logging/Write',
        data: envelope,
...

Comment: @AllenJergensen Ah, excellent.  I figured nesting the objects like you originally had would be fine but I can see how naming them explicitly like that would help.  I'll update my answer.